# AdMob libarary in iOS cause linker error(mach-o)

Tags: ios, xcode, admob, cocos2d-x

I make some game with cocos2d-x game library and I want to show banner ad with AdMob. 
With libGoogleAdMobAds.a version 6.5.0, it works fine but that version did not support arm64 architecture. And then I migrate to version 6.11.1(latest version) but it cause some linker error.

> Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
>   "_UITransitionContextToViewControllerKey"
>   "_UITransitionContextFromViewControllerKey"
>   "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_UIPercentDrivenInteractiveTransition"
>   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_UIPercentDrivenInteractiveTransition"
>   linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

What is the problem? I spent for 3 day because this error. please help me.

---

Below is whole error message.

> Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
>     "_UITransitionContextToViewControllerKey", referenced from:
>         -[GADViewControllerFullScreenSwipeAnimation animateTransition:] in libGoogleAdMobAds.a(GADViewControllerFullScreenSwipeAnimation.o)
>         -[GADViewControllerFullScreenSwipeAnimation animationContextForTopToBottomAnimationPresentationWithTransitionContext:] in libGoogleAdMobAds.a(GADViewControllerFullScreenSwipeAnimation.o)
>         -[GADViewControllerFullScreenSwipeAnimation animationContextForBottomToTopAnimationPresentationWithTransitionContext:] in libGoogleAdMobAds.a(GADViewControllerFullScreenSwipeAnimation.o)
>     "_UITransitionContextFromViewControllerKey", referenced from:
>         -[GADViewControllerFullScreenSwipeAnimation animateTransition:] in libGoogleAdMobAds.a(GADViewControllerFullScreenSwipeAnimation.o)
>         -[GADViewControllerFullScreenSwipeAnimation animationContextForRestoringAnimationToSavedState:] in libGoogleAdMobAds.a(GADViewControllerFullScreenSwipeAnimation.o)
>     "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_UIPercentDrivenInteractiveTransition", referenced from:
>         _OBJC_METACLASS_$_GADPercentDrivenUserInteractionAnimationController in libGoogleAdMobAds.a(GADPercentDrivenUserInteractionAnimationController.o)
>     "_OBJC_CLASS_$_UIPercentDrivenInteractiveTransition", referenced from:
>         _OBJC_CLASS_$_GADPercentDrivenUserInteractionAnimationController in libGoogleAdMobAds.a(GADPercentDrivenUserInteractionAnimationController.o)
>   ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Answer (score 0):

Check in your Targets->Build Phases-> Link Binary With Labraries is libGoogleAdMobAds added? If yes, than check if all required frameworks for working with AdMob are added!

Comment: Sorry I'm late. libGoogleAdMobAds.a was added and all of required frameworks was also added. Anyway I upload binary with version 6.5.0 and wait for review in apple. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should check the documentation of the latest version of AdMob, some methods may have been deprecated and removed in the latest version, and may not be available anymore ?

Comment: Sorry I'm late. I think there was no deprecated method call. because when I build it with iOS simulator(x86 architecture) build was success and everything was fine. but in iPhone5 device, build was fail with above linker error message. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably not going to like this answer, but it worked for me :)

I was getting the exact same error as you.  When I plug in an iOS device, Xcode lists the device 3 times in the device list.  On my other apps, I've always chosen to execute on the middle one.  When using AdMob, I have to select the third one in the list or I get the linker error.

If Xcode does the same thing for you, give it a try.

Since I have no idea why Xcode lists 3 devices or why the target device changes compilation, I'll be testing my build on a number of iOS devices!

Comment: It lists 3 devices because you are likely to have multiple sdks in your Xcode Sdk folder @ `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs
` .. Each device representing that SDK

Comment: In my case, there are only one device in Xcode but that's interesting and it may be the hint of my problem. I already submit my app in AppStore with another version of AdMob sdk. thanks. :)